# Would rotating detonation rocket engines always require high pressure fuel pumps?

Tags: engines, engine-design, design-alternative, turbopump, rotating-detonation-engine

The question [Performance of a pumpless liquid rocket engine](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/45347/12102) is thoughtful and provocative and pretty much all answers include a mention of the extremely high pressure necessary to push propellants into a high pressure combustion chamber and the use of turbo pumps for this purpose.

But this is based on steady-state combustion in the chamber, and the rotating detonation rocket engine is a [horse of a different color](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lN75xqpqCGE).

**Question:** Would rotating detonation rocket engines always require high pressure fuel pumps?

Comment: Yesterday's [“possible to prevent instability by injecting at choking condition?”](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/45358/is-it-impossible-to-prevent-the-combustion-instability-by-injecting-the-reactant), which doesn't seem to have reached much attention, is also highly related to this (choked flow ~ supersonic flow, detonation ~ supersonic combustion).

Comment: Aren't they air-breathing? A potential competitor to jets, not to vacuum-capable rocket engines though, it seems to me.